# This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication in release version

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I make the release build getting an error:
*This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verifythat the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ App validation failed ]*

In debug build all fine and Firebase Authentication works as it should.

Thanks

Comment: Follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46945089/5137352

Comment: Check this answer if it works https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/355#issuecomment-625185786